Why is APK not building
Whenever I try to build the APK on my phone, it returns error:
Try:

Run with --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

Expected to run absolutely perfectly

is the app build on the emulator ?

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/156307

This issue occurs because an old version of Java is being used in the project.
Open the app/build.gradle file and make the following change within the android { block:
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}


kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "21"
}

// Configure the JVM toolchain for JDK 21
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))
    }
}

after this you change pls, just run flutter clean command and then make build
